# Invalid Syntax Error on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, syntax-error

```
warrants = ["Adela","Arya","The Big D","Wei Xuen","Rebecca"]
Fines = []
totalFines= 0

def enterFine():
global totalFines

name = input("Enter the full name of the driver: ")
checkwarrant(name)

validInput = False
while validInput == False:
    try:
        speedlimit = int(input("Enter the speed limit across your area :"))
        speed = int(input("Enter the speed of the driver : "))
        amountOver = speed - speedlimit

        if amountOver > 0:
            validInput = True

            if amountOver < 10:
                print("This person should be charged $30")
                totalFines +=30
            elif amountOver < 15:
                print("This person should be charged $45")
                totalFines +=45
            elif amountOver < 20:
                print("This person should be charged $60")
                totalFines +=60
            else:
                print("This person is to be charged $420")

            fines.append([name, amountOver])
        else:
            print("Error")

    except:
        print("Error")

def checkWarrant(name):
for person in warrants:
    if person == name:
        print(person.upper(),"is wanted for using Hooktronic cheats")

def printsummary():
print("Total Fines for today :" , len(fines))
for number in range(0, len(fines)):
    print(number +1, ") Name: ", fines[number][0],"  Amount Over Limit: $", 
fines[number][1]
print("Total amount of fines: $", totalFines)

moreInput = "Y"
while moreInput == "Y":

  enterFine()

  askIntput = "X"
  while askInput != "Y" and askIntput != "N":
      askInput = input("Do you wish to enter another person to the database?
(Y/N): ")

  if askInput == "N":
      moreInput = "N"

printsummary()
```

Hi, i have an error with this code, when i run this program it comes up with an invalid syntax message. It would be nice if you guys help me out. Thank you 
Hi, i have an error with this code, when i run this program it comes up with an invalid syntax message. It would be nice if you guys help me out. Thank you Hi, i have an error with this code, when i run this program it comes up with an invalid syntax message. It would be nice if you guys help me out. Thank you Hi, i have an error with this code, when i run this program it comes up with an invalid syntax message. It would be nice if you guys help me out. Thank you Hi, i have an error with this code, when i run this program it comes up with an invalid syntax message. It would be nice if you guys help me out. Thank you Hi, i have an error with this code, when i run this program it comes up with an invalid syntax message. It would be nice if you guys help me out. Thank you Hi, i have an error with this code, when i run this program it comes up with an invalid syntax message. It would be nice if you guys help me out. Thank you

Comment: The reason SO wants you to put more text in is so that a) you can put actually relevant information, like *what the error is* and *where it is happening*, and b) so that you cut down your code to the minimum necessary rather than pasting dozens of irrelevant lines.

Comment: The `SyntaxError` should tell you which line the error is on, and what's wrong with it. If you can't understand that error, post it here and we can explain it to you. That's a lot easier than making us guess where there might be an error somewhere in dozens of lines of code.

Comment: it doesnt say on the program but i have used a python code checker and it said line 50 thank you

Comment: "It doesn't say on the program" can't be true. How are you running your script? Meanwhile, what "python code checker" did you use? And finally, what you posted clearly isn't your actual code, because what you posted raises an `IndentationError` on line 6, long before getting to line 50, which makes it even more impossible for anyone to debug this for you.

Comment: Yes, it does not say which line has an error. I cannot run the script because there is a syntax error. https://pythonbuddy.com/. They as in stack over flow told me to indent 4 times .

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of issues with your question:

1) Your code is not properly indented

2) You've intentionally pasted a lot of irrelevant text into your question.

3) You are not providing a stack trace of the error

Your code problem is that this line:

```
print(number +1, ") Name: ", fines[number][0],"  Amount Over Limit: $", fines[number][1]
```

Does not have a closing parens `)` at the end.